# Debugging secure websocket traffic on android

Tags: proxy, android

Anyone have any good recommendations for debugging/intercepting the secure websocket traffic directed at any given port from an app running on my android? Trying to do some testing and other apps like sandroproxy and proxydroid haven't worked.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: The best websocket debugger I found was actually Fiddler....give it a try. Reverse engineering the code always works as well.

Comment: I tried Fiddler. It works very well. The app is sending hex, so I need to find out what the hex means by analyzing the app code.